# How to use IDA pro to convert a batch of binary PE files into assembly code?

Tags: ida, idapython, pe, ida-plugin

I have a batch of binary PE files, and I want to convert them into assembly code using IDA pro. Do you know IDA command/plugin to automatically convert all of them?